# Draw octagon with color node at middle edges

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw three pictures in TikZ but I don't know how to do it.

[image: wanted]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Comment: You find *many* examples at http://texample.net Try finding one that you can adapt; if your attempts don't work, then you'll have some code and adding it to your question will make people here help you.

Comment: Remember to accept the answer you find most useful (if, indeed, any of them are useful to you).

Answer (score 11):

No comments!

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=4mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}
    \node[draw,thick,minimum size=4cm,name=O,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=8] {};
    \foreach \x in {1,2,...,8}{
     \node[fill=red,circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] at (O.side \x) {};
     \node[fill,circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] at (O.corner \x) {};     
    }
    \node[fill=green,circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] at (O.center) {};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[xshift=5cm]
      \node[draw,thick,minimum size=4cm,name=O,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4] {};
    \foreach \x in {1,2,...,4}{
     \node[fill=red,circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] at (O.side \x) {};
     \node[fill,circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] at (O.corner \x) {};
    }
    \node[fill=green,circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] at (O.center) {};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[xshift=9cm]
      \node[draw,thick,minimum size=2cm,name=O,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4,rotate=40] {};
    \foreach \x in {1,2,...,4}{     
     \node[fill=red,circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] at (O.corner \x) {};
    }
    \node[fill=green,circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] at (O.center) {};
    \node[fill,circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] (t) at ([shift={(-8mm,2cm)}]O.corner 1) {};
    \foreach \x in {2,...,4}{
     \draw (O.corner \x) -- (t);
    }
    \draw[dashed] (O.corner 1) -- (t);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is for Svend Tveskæg, simpler version:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=4mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{mypolygon/.pic={%
    \begin{scope}
    \node[draw,thick,minimum size=4cm,name=O,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=#1] {};
    \foreach \x in {1,2,...,#1}{
     \node[fill=red,circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] at (O.side \x) {};
     \node[fill,circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] at (O.corner \x) {};
    }
    \node[fill=green,circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] at (O.center) {};
    \end{scope}
  }
}


\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic {mypolygon={8}};
    \pic at (5,0) {mypolygon={4}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and the show spoiler:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=4mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{pics/.cd,
mypolygon/.style args={#1 and #2}{%
        code = {%
    \begin{scope}
    \node[draw,thick,minimum size=#2,name=O,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=#1] {};
    \foreach \x in {1,2,...,#1}{
     \node[fill=red,circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] at (O.side \x) {};
     \node[fill,circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] at (O.corner \x) {};
    }
    \node[fill=green,circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] at (O.center) {};
    \end{scope}
  }
}}


\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic {mypolygon={9 and 4cm}};
    \pic at (5,0) {mypolygon={4 and 6cm}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to create a 'general' macro as done in the [PSTricks solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/227280/15874) (and if so, can I make you do it)? I don't know TikZ myself but I would like to learn it some day.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Thank you. You are welcome :-) If you want to vary size, add `#2` and adjust `minimum size=#2 cm` in node declaration.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Here comes the better version. See the edit.

Answer (score 7):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{xfp}

% polygon drawing
\newcommand*\polygon[2]{%
\def\spacing{0.04}% spacing for the boundind box
\begin{pspicture}%
(\fpeval{cos(pi*(1-2*ceil(0.5*#2))/#2)*#1-\spacing},
 \fpeval{sin(pi*(1-2*ceil(0.25*#2))/#2)*#1-\spacing})%
(\fpeval{cos(pi/#2)*#1+\spacing},
 \fpeval{sin(pi*(1-2*ceil(0.75*#2))/#2)*#1+\spacing})
  \psdot[dotstyle = o, fillcolor = green](0,0)
  \multido{\i = 1+1}{#2}{%
     \psdot(\fpeval{cos(pi/#2*(2*\i-1))*#1},\fpeval{sin(pi/#2*(2*\i-1))*#1})
    \psline(\fpeval{cos(pi/#2*(2*\i-1))*#1},\fpeval{sin(pi/#2*(2*\i-1))*#1})%
           (\fpeval{cos(pi/#2*(2*\i+1))*#1},\fpeval{sin(pi/#2*(2*\i+1))*#1})
     \psdot[dotstyle = o, fillcolor = red]%
           (\fpeval{cos(pi/#2)*cos(2*pi/#2*\i)*#1},\fpeval{cos(pi/#2)*sin(2*pi/#2*\i)*#1})}
\end{pspicture}}

\begin{document}

\polygon{2.2}{8}
\enskip
\polygon{2}{4}
\enskip
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,5)
  \psdot[dotstyle = o, fillcolor = green](0,0)
  \psdot(-0.7,5)
  \psline[linestyle = dashed](0,2)(-0.7,5)
  \psline(2,0)(-0.7,5)
  \psline(-2,0)(-0.7,5)
  \psline(0,-2)(-0.7,5)
  \pspolygon(2,0)(0,2)(-2,0)(0,-2)
  \psdots[dotstyle = o, fillcolor = red](2,0)(0,2)(-2,0)(0,-2)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Notice that the first two figures are drawn using the general marco

```
\polygon{<radius of the circumcircle>}{<number of sides in the regular polygon>}
```

These drawings can be created quite a lot easier by using the [`pst-poly`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-poly) package but for some (at this point unknown to me) reason this package is not working on any of my systems. Therefore, I have used a more cumbersome approach in order to be abel to test the code before releasing it.

Answer (score 4):

A MetaPost version included in a LuaLaTeX program (without comments either).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}

  vardef regpoly(expr n) =
    save angl; angl = 360/n;
    (right for i = 1 upto n-1: -- dir(i*angl) endfor -- cycle) rotated 0.5angl
  enddef;

  vardef regpoly_withdots(expr n, radius) =
    save polygon; path polygon; 
    polygon = regpoly(n) scaled radius; draw polygon;
    drawoptions(withpen pencircle scaled 3bp);
    drawdot origin withcolor green;
    for i = 0 upto n: 
      drawdot (point i of polygon);
      drawdot 0.5[point i of polygon, point i+1 of polygon] withcolor red;
    endfor;
    drawoptions();
  enddef;

  u = cm; r = 2u;

  beginfig(0);

    regpoly_withdots(8, r);

    draw image(regpoly_withdots(4, r)) shifted (2.5r, 0);

    draw image(
      z = (-.75, 4)*u ;
      path quadri; quadri = regpoly(4) scaled 0.5r rotated 38; draw quadri; 
      draw z -- point 0 of quadri dashed evenly;
      for i = 1 upto 3: draw z -- (point i of quadri) ; endfor ;
      drawoptions(withpen pencircle scaled 3bp);
      drawdot origin withcolor green;
      for i = 0 upto 3: drawdot (point i of quadri) withcolor red; endfor;
      drawdot z; drawoptions();
    ) shifted (4.5r, 0);

  endfig;

\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know TikZ but is it possible to create a general macro as I've done using PSTricks? (If it is possible and it's not too difficult, can I make you create it?)

Comment: @SvendTveskæg I would say it is possible, but I don't know tikz much either. Did you mean MetaPost (in that case the answer is yes of course, see my regpoly_withdots macro above) or did you mean to ask Harish Kumar instead of me?

Comment: I meant MetaPost; sorry. `:)`